# Using a Three Digit ASCII Code in a Regex

Tags: regex

Is it possible to use a three digit ASCII code in a PCRE regex? A space character is a two digit one (40). You need to add a zero and escape it like so: \040

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can easily use octal escapes up to `\377` in normal and `\777` in UTF-8 mode. To quote from the [manpage](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> **Non-printing characters**
>
> A second use of backslash provides a way of encoding non-printing char-
>    acters  in patterns in a visible manner. There is no restriction on the
>    appearance of non-printing characters, apart from the binary zero  that
>    terminates  a  pattern,  but  when  a pattern is being prepared by text
>    editing, it is usually easier  to  use  one  of  the  following  escape
>    sequences than the binary character it represents:
>
> ```
> ...
> \ddd        character with octal code ddd, or backreference
> \xhh        character with hex code hh
> \x{hhh..}   character with hex code hhh..
> ```

I've included the hexadecimal escapes in this quote because they're quite likely easier to read and don't clash with backreferences. So depending on how often you use `\123` it might be more sensible to resort to `\x53`.

Comment: @lanmind: If you want to increase the chance that other questions get answered, you should start accepting answers by pressing the green tick-button at the left. This marks the question as answered correctly. @Johannes: +1 for a great answer with simplicity and clarity